# MP3 Chapter player

Tags: linux, audio, software-rec

Is there a mp3 player that has support for [mp3-chapters](http://id3.org/id3v2-chapters-1.0) (beyond mpv)?

I have some big mp3 files with chapters and using mpv for playback is a bit cumbersome when I have over 100 chapters per file.

The way I do it now is:

```
mpv --force-window file.mp3
```

Then I set OSD on by pressing Shift+F9 having this in my `input.conf` for mpv:

```
SHIFT+F9 script-message osc-visibility always
```

This does not show chapter though.

Using PageUp/Down one can go to next/previous chapter.

Using the window previous/next is a bit better as it flashes the chapters and one get an idea on where one are at.

I tried to always show chapters by:

```
F9 script-message osc-chapterlist 500
```

where 500 is seconds to show. Problem is that the list is not updated when chapters change.

What I am looking for is a player that preferably list all chapters and give the option to jump to them.

## Case:

*A little background on the case:*

I use `mpv` to record some audio streams simplified:

```
mpv \
    --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsock \
    --record-file=out.mp3 \
    url
```

Simultaneously I use a Python script with *socket* to save *icy-title* with timestamp on change to `out.log`.

After this I post process by using python + [mutagen to add chapters](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/id3.html#chapter-extension) to the saved mp3 based on the log file.

The *ICY-data* is not exact enough to do splits, and it is very convenient to have it all in one file / container instead of split into hundreds of files.

That said - I would find it useful to use this option on other files as well. (Not only the recording mentioned above).

Comment: What OS does it need to run on?

Comment: @JeffSchaller:  I am currently running  Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS